# Log from Rebus to Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, rebus

When running a Rebus service bus, how would you set Rebus up to log to Application Insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to configure Rebus to use Serilog, and then use [the Application Insights sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights) to pipe logs as trace or event telemetry.

Something like this:

```
// global Serilog config
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.ColoredConsole()
    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(...) //< fill in instrumentation key etc here
    .CreateLogger();

// configure Rebus
Configure.With(activator)
    .Logging(l => l.Serilog())
    .Transport(t => t.UseInMemoryTransport(new InMemNetwork(), "logging-test"))
    .Start();
```